# Is it possible to read emails (content) through gmail gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gmail

```
@messages=gmail.mailbox('[Gmail]/All Mail').search(:from => options[:user])
  @messages.each do |email|
    say email.uid
  end
```

Hi, I used the above to get all the mails from a specific user and then to iterate through their uid's.

Used the gmail gem for this: https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail

The method works well and I get the array of @messages. How can I read through each of the mail. As in if I wanted the subject of each mail or the body?

Thanks.

Comment: What about mail.message? See https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail/blob/master/lib/gmail/message.rb